# Dictionary value to key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary file with words from english language on the left and the definiton of the words in another language on the right. Something like this:

```
a little    xxx, xxx, xxx
a little at a time  xxx
a little too thick  xxx xxx xxx
a lot   xxx, xxx, xxx
a lot alike xxx xxx
```

And I have the program to read the from the file, which needs to stay like this:

```
fail = open("English_dictionary.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
dictionary = {}
for row in fail:
    words = row.split("\t")
    xxx_word = words[0]
    english_word = words[1]
    dictionary[xxx_word] = english_word
fail.close()
```

The point is, I have to write a program, that asks the user to input a word from the other language(right side), and the program gives the definition of the xxx word in english. So basically from value to key. And the question needs to be repeatedly asked so I started it like this, but now Im stuck because I don't know how to get the key definition when I have the value.

```
a = 0
while a == 0:
     word = input("Insert xxx word: ")


     break
```

Comment: give us what the dictionary looks like after the reading, so we don't have to deal with reading part.

Comment: It seems to me you want two dictionaries: one that maps non-English words to English words, and another that maps English words to their definitions.  So you look up the word in the first dict to get the English word, then use that to retrieve the definition from the second dict.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries do not work like that. They work by looking up a key to get a value. You should invert your dictionary, and then look up accordingly.

```
inv_map = {v: k for k, v in my_map.items()}
```

Edit: I am not sure if I converted the dictionary correctly. If you input 'tublisti kõvasti, palju', you will get 'a lot'

```
dict = {
'a little too thick': 'pisut liiga paks',
'a lot': 'tublisti kõvasti, palju',
'a lot alike': 'tublisti sarnane',
'a matter of time': 'aja küsimus',
'a million': 'miljon',
'a native of': 'pärit',
'a number of hulk': 'palju, mitmed',
'a number of times': 'korduvalt'
}

inv_dict = {v: k for k, v in dict.items()}

while (True):
    word = input("Insert xxx word:")
    if (word in inv_dict):
        print(inv_dict[word])
        break
```

Comment: Is there really no other way without inverting the dictionary. I also  tried this bit of code but did not seem to get it working.

Comment: The problem here is you are trying to look up a key by value. If you invert the dictionary, that lookup becomes a proper dictionary lookup by looking up the value by key. change my_map to dictionary (your variable), and perform your lookup on inv_map. If you are looking up a value that was originally in your dictionary, you will get the key.

Comment: I am still getting a key error. I am currently using "for" program. Should I be doing it differently?

Comment: If you are getting a key error after inverting the dictionary, then the key you are searching must not be a value in the original dictionary. Can you confirm if this is the case? I am unsure what you mean by using "for" program

Comment: For example, if your dictionary = {"a little too thick": "xxx xxx xxx"}, inv_map = {"xxx xxx xxx": "a little too thick"}. If you search "xxx xxx xxx" in inv_map, you should get "a little too thick"

Comment: inverted = {v : k for k, v in dictionary.items()}

a = 0
while a == 0:
    word = input("Insert xxx word: ")
    for word in inverted:
        print(inverted[word])
        break

Comment: I was using something like this

Comment: I think you should change the for to an if.

Comment: Now it literally does not print anything, just repeats the input.

Comment: Can you provide a sample dictionary for me to test with?